# Loopback Update User Field

Tags: rest, http, loopback

I am trying to update a field in a model that extends the user model. In the API explorer, I set the `where` field to `{"id": 59}`, and have the access token one that corresponds with `id 59`. In the data field I have `{"age": 55}` where I am just trying to update the age to 55.

The request URL ends up being: `http://IP:3000/api/MODEL/update?where=%7B%22id%22%3A%2059%7D&access_token=LONG ACCESS TOKEN VALUE`

Which gives an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 401,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Authorization Required",
    "code": "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED",
    }
}
```

I don't understand why authorization is required when I have a correct access token and the email has been verified. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Loopback by default provides `ACL` to user model. So by default the `update` operation can only be changed by the `$OWNER`, ie. the person himself.

So first login with the `username` and `password`, you get the accesstoken. Copy and set the `accesstoken` in `Api Explorer`.

Now use the `PUT` method, which will say `Users/{$id}`

Open it and you will see 2 fields, `data` and `id`. Provide your model's `id` and provide the data object (the data that needs to be changed)

Hope this helps.